# JSP HTML Errors

Tags: jsp

I am using a combination of HTML and JSP and Eclipse (Springsource) is showing errors when I put JSP inside of an HTML tag or javascript.

```
<body onload="script();
 <c:forEach var="assocObjType"
     items="${assocTypes}">script2('${assocObjType.param}');
 </c:forEach>">
```

Am i doing something wrong or is there a way to turn this off? when i remove the c:forEach part, the page is fine, but with that in there the whole page is red underlines..

thanks in advance

Comment: What you've posted isn't even vaguely well-formed, you've got stuff missing all over the place. Is this just a typo?

Comment: the project builds fine, the error is "isValid()==false" and its just a matter of working  in a page full of red squiggles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP/EL validation in Eclipse is an epic fail. Just ignore it and run it. If it doesn't work as expected (rightclick, choose *View Source* to check generated HTML to be sure). If those Eclipse errors bother you, just turn off JSP/EL validation in Eclipse preferences.